# Non-exclusive shared memory lock in C

Tags: c, locking, semaphore

I'm on Linux and I want to share memory between about 5-10 processes (each is a C program).  I know how to do this with either the POSIX semaphores (sem_open, sem_wait, sem_post, etc) or the other semaphores (semctl, semget, semop, etc).  The problem is I only know how to do exclusive semaphore locks.  I want non-exclusive locks.

In my application, only one process writes to shared memory, while all others only read it.  I'd like to be able to do non-exclusive read locks on the semaphore (like with the shell command flock).  Can I do this with POSIX semaphores or semctl()?  Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The tool for you are read-write locks `pthread_rwlock_t`. Linux implements them well in shared memory between different processes. Have a look into `pthread_rwlock_init`, `pthread_rwlockattr_init` and `pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared` to see how to enable them in shared memory.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that only work for pthreads?  My app consists of several different processes (not threads).

Comment: Yes, it works between processes, that's what I was trying to say, and that's what `pthread_rwlockattr_setpshared` enables.